# Popping from stack base

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, stack-memory

I'm making an operating system for fun, whilist learning more Assembly on the way.
I learned about pushing and popping, as I understand, pop takes the value that is on top of any other value on the stack, so it gets the last pushed one. But I wonder, can we actually directly pop the value at the stack base (i.e. the first pushed one)?

Like:

```
push 'A'
push 'B'
push 'C'

pop bx ; Gets C
```

Instead of C, I want to get A as an example.
(I'm in 16-bit mode, and the assembler is NASM, specified in the tags as well.)

Comment: In truth, the stack is fictitious, in the sense that the elements of the stack don't get relocated every time you `pop`. Instead, the CPU does something much easier that gets the same end result: it uses what's called a "stack pointer" which references whatever the topmost item is (or on some other architectures the first "free" slot). Every time you `push` the CPU subtracts 2 from `sp` and every time you `pop` the CPU adds 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write down the layout of the stack in memory.  You'll see that “popping” any element in the middle of the stack would entail shuffling a lot stack elements around in memory.  Processors don't have support for that.  You can however load any element on the stack into a register at any time without popping it (i.e. it'll still be on the stack afterwards).

To do so, first copy the stack pointer into some register that can be used for addressing memory (`bp` is the canonical choice), then access the stack from that.

```
mov bp, sp      ; make the stack accessible
mov bx, [bp+4]  ; load stack element A into bx
```

Usually, `bp` is set up as a part of establishing a stack frame for the current function, so you have it always available for accessing the stack.  You can also use the registers `bx`, `si`, and `di`, but keep in mind that a `ss` segment override is needed in that case (it's implicit for `bp`).

Now, why do we have to add 4 to get item A?  Recall that the stack grows towards lower addresses in memory (i.e. with each `push`, `sp` is decreased) and each stack slot occupies 2 bytes of memory in 16 bit mode.  So assuming `sp = 1000h` after your sequence of pushes, we have the following memory layout:

```
1004h  A
1002h  B
1000h  C  <-- SP
```

so by simple arithmetic, `SP + 4` points at stack slot A and `SP + 2` at stack slot B.

Comment: How can I get 'B' in this case? And why we add 4? Adding 8 doesn't work to get 'B', so why 4 for 'A'?

Comment: @triangleBoi added a bit to the answer about that.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I'm not an Assembly expert, you helped me a lot.

Comment: If you don't care about the other letters and just want 'A' you can do `pop bx pop bx pop bx`

Answer (score 2):

In 16-bit mode, there's no `sp` relative addressing mode, but you can copy the value in `sp` into, say, `bp`, and use `bp` relative addressing to access A's location.  This won't pop A, of course, but you can read or write A.

This is one reason why x86 functions often have `mov bp,sp` in their prologue (function startup code).  Once `bp` is set up to refer to its stack, a function can access the parameters that its caller pushed using `bp` relative addressing (`bp` + displacement).